# Cleaning out a smell

Tags: spices, cleaning

Trying to clean out the spice cabinet and I want to re-purpose a shaker from a chili powder based mix to a cinnamon-sugar (it's made principally of plastic but has wire mesh screen). After a couple of washings the smell of chili powder is still pretty evident. How can I clean out that smell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try baking soda. It is well known for absorbing odors, especially in plastic.

Answer (score 4):

Try some hydrogen peroxide. A lot of colors and odors can be removed with peroxide.